# Weeks and days between two dates - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to simply display the weeks and days until next Christmas. I can currently get the weeks to display or the days to display but not at the same time.

This is my html file.
     
     
     Date Calculator in JavaScript

```
 <script src="datecalculator.js"> </script>

 <style>

  p 
  {
    color:red;        
  }

  .dateformat
  {
    background-color: yellow;
  }


  </style>

  </head>

 <body> 

 <script>
  function getDate()
  { 
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Today's date is: " + new Date();  
  }

 </script>

 <button onclick="getDate()">Get Today's Date</button> <br/> <br />

 <button onclick="daystoChristmas()"> Get Days left until next   Christmas </button>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <p id="demo1" class="dateformat"></p>

 </body> 
 </html>
```

This is my external javascript file:

```
function daystoChristmas()
{ 

today = new Date();
window.alert("Today's date is: " + today);
xmas = new Date("December 25, 2016");    
msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
msLeft = (xmas.getTime() - today.getTime());
daysLeft = Math.round(msLeft/msPerDay);      
document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = daysLeft + " Days left    until next Christmas";
```

}

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Allow me to suggest posting your code on https://jsfiddle.net/ - that way folks can try it live and edit.  I've seen a number of questions where having the fiddle was very helpful to those answering.

Comment: Where is the `weeks` code? Nothing in question has anything to do with weeks

Comment: The code displayed just shows the amount of days until next christmas and so I want to incorporate weeks into the code alongside the days.

Comment: Basically the weeks and days until christmas 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```js
function daystoChristmas()
{ 

today = new Date();
window.alert("Today's date is: " + today);
xmas = new Date("December 25, 2016");    
msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
msLeft = (xmas.getTime() - today.getTime());
daysLeft = Math.round(msLeft/msPerDay);
weeksLeft = Math.floor(daysLeft/7);
daysLeft = daysLeft % 7;
document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = weeksLeft + " weeks and "+daysLeft+" days left    until next Christmas"; 
}
```

```html
<style>

  p 
  {
    color:red;        
  }

  .dateformat
  {
    background-color: yellow;
  }


  </style>

  </head>

 <body> 

 <script>
  function getDate()
  { 
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Today's date is: " + new Date();  
  }

 </script>

 <button onclick="getDate()">Get Today's Date</button> <br/> <br />

 <button onclick="daystoChristmas()"> Get Days left until next   Christmas </button>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <p id="demo1" class="dateformat"></p>

 </body>
```